# not authorized to perform: ses:UpdateTemplate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use Lambda to update an SES email template (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/ses-template.html) but it complains about not having permission even if I give it blanket SES permissions. (`SES:*`)

I've tried using both the `UpdateTemplate` and `UpdateEmailTemplate` in the IAM role as I can see there are both of these for SES 1 and SES 2 respectively.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/index.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sesv2/index.html

The error is: `not authorized to perform: ses:UpdateTemplate`

This happens even with all permissions set for SES.  The only thing I can think of is I need to specify I am talking about SES v2 not 1 but even if I use the policy generator it classifies it as just `ses` without any marker to imply it's for v2.

It seems to me that AWS are still using both and that v2 does not actually supersede 1 somehow but I'd love to have even this part cleared up but can't see any clarifications online.

Any clues to get me back on the road with this would be massively apreciated!

Edit: Just to add that I'm using serverless https://www.serverless.com/ and my IAM declaration looks like this:

```
- Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - SES:SendEmail
        - SES:SendRawEmail
        - SES:SendBulkTemplatedEmail
        - SES:UpdateEmailTemplate
        - SES:UpdateTemplate

      Resource: "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:*:*"
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you confirm that you are using SES in us-east-1?

Comment: Thanks! Yes `us-east-1` is where the party is :)

Comment: Are you applying these permissions to the role that is running the lambda or to some other role?  I'm just making sure the lambda console permissions shows it running under the role you expect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is the corrrect role and function as the other functions like send email work, the above is set in the main declaration so should apply to all functions :)

Comment: To be certain the lambda is using the correct role, you can check the Permissions subtab on the Configuration tab of the lambda to see what role it lists.